# Can a too high MySQL innodb buffer pool size cause high load by kernel swap daemon (kswapd0)?

Tags: mysql, web-services, linux-kernel, kernel

What are the best practices to analyze and avoid appearance of high load which is caused by kernel swap daemon? Does it have a direct effect from the MySQL configurations of the buffer pool size, etc.. ?

Answer (score 1):

In a stable Linux system the swap file should barely be used at all, as soon as it is then your system will slow to a crawl. It exists for three reasons, overcommit accounting (which no longer applies these days), to swap out unused code segments to disk to make more room for disk buffers, and to give you more warning when you're running out of memory before the `oom_killer` starts terminating your applications.

MySQL bypasses the kernel's in-built disk buffering for various reasons. When it starts up it allocates the buffer pool and caches pages from the disk there. When the buffer pool is full it will remove some clean pages, and write-out some dirty pages to make room for more.

If you set the buffer pool to be larger than the amount of RAM you have available then as RAM fills up the kernel will start swapping pages out to the swap file. When the buffer pool fills up MySQL will start swapping out pages to the database files. This will cause thrashing and generally bad performance as all your I/O operations will be multiplied by (at minimum) three.

This is most likely what you're seeing, I'd suggest you reduce the size of the buffer pool so that it fits in your free RAM.

Comment: Thx. Current MySQL configuration takes 73% of total RAM (total is 48GB) on a dedicated db server as I understood recommended range is 50%-80%. As a thumb rule, how lower would you recommend to try? 65%? Is there a way to check out much 'FREE RAM' I can spare for MySQL?

Comment: Have a look at the output of "free -g", the "-/+ buffers/cache" line will show you the free/used memory and the line below will show you the same for swap. You should be able to figure out how much is available from that.

Comment: I ran and the output shows -/+ buffers/cache: used 37 free: 9 and two lines of Swap: used 1 free 0. Is this reasonable? Why is he using swap if there still is free memory?

Comment: You have an unreasonably small amount of swap space, around a gigabyte, you have 48GB of RAM available you should definitely have more. If that was with MySQL running and warmed up then you should be ok, if that was without then you can't afford to allocate much RAM for it all. It's using swap despite there being free memory so it can fit more disk buffers in the free RAM. There's always bound to be code that's not in use and can be swapped out.